# Several instances of one program, something to open/restore all layout after minimizing them e.g. Notepad

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

A simple example, I run notepad.exe twice and I want the window layouts to be minimized with one icon on the taskbar and all windows restored with just one click.

Currently, you have to click on the thumbnail (icon) and click on the preview of the instance to open it in the way it was left. Instead of opening all instances with a mouse click.

The same can be presented on the browser. We run e.g. 3 instances, place them on the desktop and want to call the same layout with one button. Without clicking 3 times on the preview.

How to do such a thing?